# Points in edit mode are being clipped

Tags: vertices

I'm running into a glitch where some of my mesh goes missing in edit mode. It appears that the points are clipped to a certain rhombus-like "region."
[image]
How can I remove this restriction so that I can go back to editing all points?

context: I am using Blender 2.8

Comment: In Edit Mode go to Mesh->Show/hide->Reveal All or Alt+h and then can you select and edit all the vertices?

Comment: Hi! I have already tried revealing all hidden vertices (both through the menu and using the shortcut Alt+H.) The weird thing is, none of them are "hidden" they're just being clipped by this random border. To elaborate, when I move the object along the X, I can see points on the other end as long as they're in the same region as the visible points shown above.

Comment: can you post the .blend https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ just include the affected mesh/es

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6471" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6471/)

Comment: View->View Region->Clipping Region or Alt+b

Comment: Yes!!!!! This did the trick :-) Thank you so much

I can't imagine why anyone would need to clip their edit region, but I'm relieved to know what to do for next time